# In ElasticSearch bulk upload, how do I insert data with a single quote?

Tags: bash, curl, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

How can I bulk insert data into ElasticSearch that contains a single quote inside the data?  Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/example1/example2/_bulk' -d'¬
{ "delete" : { "_id" : "1" } } ¬
{ "create" : { "_id" : "1" } } ¬
{ "name" : "John's House" }¬ '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed single-quotes within single-quotes.
But you can break out of a single-quoted string and then "insert" a single-quote there:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/example1/example2/_bulk' -d'¬
{ "delete" : { "_id" : "1" } } ¬
{ "create" : { "_id" : "1" } } ¬
{ "name" : "John'\''s House" }'
                ^ ^^
                | ||
                | |└ start new single-quoted string
                | └- escaped single quote outside of single-quoted string
                └--- close previously started single-quoted string
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to double the single quote like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/example1/example2/_bulk' -d'
{ "delete" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "create" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "name" : "John''s House" }'
                 ^
                 |
       add a second single quote
```